# Probability of an atom wanting to Excite/Deexcite in the state of Population Inversion

Tags: laser

I know that population inversion is achieved when the *probability of stimulated emissions* is **greater** than the *probability of absorptions*. But after the state is achieved, if $E_1 < E_2$ then what will be the probability of an atom wanting to excite from $E_{\text{1}}$ to $E_{\text{2}}$ versus the probability of an atom wanting to de-excite from $E_{\text{2}}$ to $E_{\text{1}}$?

I thought that if population inversion has been achieved because the probability of excitation is greater than the probability of de-excitation, then the same reasoning should apply in my question too. Is my reasoning correct? Any help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- 50/50. At the point of inversion both probabilities are the same.

2-I think you are missing some key points here. You always need to include the energy structure. For example in a 4-level system: $E_0$ ground level, $E_1$ upper pump level, $E_2$ upper laser level, $E_3$ lower laser level. The inversion between ground state $E_0$ and upper-pump level $E_1$ is always close to 0. And the population of the lower laser level $E_3$ is always really low. This means that 1: you always have a high probability of exciting an electron from $E_0$ to $E_1$ because the occupancy of $E_1$ is low. And 2: that for virtually every electron decaying from $E_1$ to $E_2$ you achieve inversion. And after an electron falls back to $E_3$, it almost immediately goes down to $E_0$ again. This leaves the lower laser level practically free, and with lack of electrons to be excited back from $E_3$ to $E_2$.

What this entails is that you virtually achieve very high values of inversion with low effort. The probability of emission becomes much higher than that of absorption with "just a handful of electrons". Or in other words, if the only electrons of your system are in the upper laser level, even if just a few, the only probable thing is that they will de-excite and emit a photon.

This is of course simplifying things a bit, not going to extreme pumping or lasing, but should clear the confusion.

Decided to add another point:

What you describe above is also called the transparency point. At that point (lets call it 50/50) the net gain is 0. You sometimes absorb, sometimes emit. You need to picture all these processes with the energy level scheme though. You reach that point by pumping just a bit that the excitation gets enough electrons to match the number of electrons on the lower and not very populated level.

Comment: I'm not getting the logic behind the __50/50__ probability, are you saying that if only **one** atom is left in the lower lasing level $E_{\text{1}}$ (**hypothetically**), then it has an equal probability of excitation as an atom in $E_{\text{2}}$ has of de-excitation? It's pretty counter intuitive tbh.

Comment: Also, in a regular case of pumping, if $E_{\text{2}}$ is metastable state and if all the atoms truly are in $E_{\text{2}}$, then why would it undergo stimulated emissions?

Comment: You specified the **point of inversion** in your question: i.e. population in upper and lower level **are the same**. As soon as population is higher on upper, you have real inversion. At the point where both have the same population though, in the presence of a photon for that transition, the probability for absorption or emission is the same. So yes, a single electron in the lower level has the same probability. Do not forget that in normal cases you have a much higher percentage of electrons in the upper level, and the net effect is of stimulated emission, not absorption.

Comment: 2nd question- To answer why they undergo stimulated emission, we need a lot of quantum mechanics background. But I think you are confusing stimulated and spontaneous emission with your second question. Might it be?

Comment: as an analogy, the transition $E_2$-$E_3$ is a resonance of the system. Now imagine the system as being a tuning fork for the note of A. If you bang it (you excite it) it will emit the note A. If you have it "quiet" and play and A on a violin, the tuning fork will also resonate and "absorb" part of the acoustic wave. Now the 50/50 part is when you "shook" the tuning fork the right amount, where it is now being transparent by emitting and absorbing the same amounts.

Comment: Ok, I guess I need to read up more on this topic, though I understood the point you were trying to make. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108578/discussion-between-jose-andrade-and-firefox1921).